# jquery.transit: rotation about given point

Tags: jquery

I'm using [transit plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to rotate A`<div>`. This rotate the element about center point, but I want to rotate them from bottom-center point. Is it possible? 
It's the style of `<div>`:

```
#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
}
```

Exactly I want rotate it from head of triangle in bottom.

**UPDATE:**
You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BbKLM/2/

Comment: Could you pleasy provide the jquery-code aswell? E.g. in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @StefanNeubert I put my code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works even in older IE versions (Without animation support):

```
        var x = $('#tri1').outerWidth() / 2;
        var y = $('#tri1').outerHeight();
        $('#tri1').css({ transformOrigin: x + 'px ' + y + 'px' });
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbKLM/2/) for complete code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS3's `transform-origin`, and set it to `center bottom`. For webkit/chrome, use the -webkit prefix:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbKLM/4/

Comment: what about IE? this should support IE also